# How to set intellij so it forces the static final variable in the format of VAR_NAME

Tags: intellij-idea

For the following code, how to get warning in intellij ?

```
private static final int varInt = 0;
```

What i want to see is

```
private static final int VAR_INT = 0;
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Editor
- Inspections
- Java
- Naming Conventions
- Field naming conventions

From the right menu you may decide `pattern`, `min` and `max length`. After that, the naming which doesn't match the convention will be show as "warning"(You may edit it too on the severity tab)

[image: Example]

After the changes you may <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> to select from available names.

[image]